# Using Google GDATA API to batch add users to groups

Tags: c#, api, gdata

I am trying to use the GDATA API to batch add users to a Google group in C#. Adding one user at a time using Groups.AddMemberToGroup takes a while to run.

There is a Groups.Batch method, but I have not been able to find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is no C# batch example for the Provisioning API, but the Spreadsheets API documentation includes one that might be useful to get started with:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#updating_multiple_cells_with_a_batch_request